# Unable to create MVC relationships with multiple items of same type

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a class `Request`, that I would like to have two properties, `BudgetHolder` and `FinancialController`, both of a single type - `Employee`.  I'm trying to do this in using a Code-First approach to the database in MVC 4.

When I use the `update-database` command I get the following error

```
Error: The new name 'BudgetHolderId' is already in use as a COLUMN name and would cause a duplicate that is not permitted.
```

Ultiamtely I'm to create a page that will allow a Request to be created to show two drop downs with a list of Employees in each, but currently all that is shown are textboxes for `BudgetHolderId` and `FinancialControllerId`

My current code is as follows.

```
public class Request
{
    public virtual int BudgetHolderId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BudgetHolderId")]
    public virtual Employee BudgetHolder { get; set; }

    public virtual int FinancialControllerId { get; set; }        
    [ForeignKey("FinancialControllerId")]
    public virtual Employee FinancialController { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm still not certain why the above did not work, but my solution was to change the declaration above to the following

```
public class Request
{
    public virtual int BudgetHolderEmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("BudgetHolderEmployeeId")]
    public virtual Employee BudgetHolder { get; set; }

    public virtual int FinancialControllerEmployeeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("FinancialControllerEmployeeId")]
    public virtual Employee FinancialController { get; set; }
}
```

I would guess that there is an implicit item called `BudgetHolderId` and `FinancialControllerId` that was preventing me from declaring my own variables/columns with the same names.

Either way, the above now compiles, and when a new RequestController is generated the existing Employees are included as drop down lists.